# Erro 404 ao atualizar a pagina - Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-routes

Galera é o seguinte, comecei um novo projeto em Angular 4 e ele funciona perfeitamente no localhost. Subi para o servidor (Tomcat) e fui testar, ao pesquisar pela url `http://aplicativo.com/teste` ele me redireciona para `http://aplicativo.com/teste/home` (padrão) até ai tudo bem, porém quando eu atualizo a página (`F5`) ele me mostra o erro `HTTP Status 404 - /teste/home`

Obs: Se eu, com a pagina `teste/home` sendo exibida, ir no campo de pesquisa por url que contem `http://aplicativo.com/teste/home` e dar `ENTER` ele também me mostra o mesmo erro `HTTP Status 404 - /teste/home`

Como corrigir isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação as rotas padrões tem que redirecionar pro index https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

reescreva o .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

para configuração especifica do apache: https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

**OUTRA SOLUÇÃO**

Ao invés de atualizar seu servidor para servir o index.html, basta mudar para a abordagem HashBand.

Importar no app.module.ts:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

E adicionar no NgModule:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Comment: caraca valeu mano, eu não tinha achado na documentação mas com isso eu consegui  !!